# Comparing keypressed to a char

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make some sort of typing game in python using pygame. So, if the key pressed character is the same as the character in the word, it should return true... Is there any way to do this in python?

For example:
the word is "cat", if the user presses the key 'c', then it returns true... and so on for the rest of the characters.

## here's my main.py file

```
from time import sleep
import pygame
import random
import winsound
from words import Words

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE =  (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED =   (255,   0,   0)

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

w1 = Words(screen) #making a single word (for now) to see if typing works

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


    screen.fill(WHITE)
    w1.draw()

    #attempting to write code here to compare word and user input



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.init()
exit()
```

## here's my words.py file

```
from random_words import RandomWords
import pygame
import random
from queue import *

rw = RandomWords()

class Words():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.x_point = 400
        self.y_point = 400
        self.word = rw.random_word() #generates a random word
        self.queue = Queue() #was hoping to use the queue so that if the user types the char correctly in the right order, then the letter would change color or something (but that's further down the line)
        for c in self.word: #iterate through randomized word.. 
            self.queue.put(c) #add each char in randomized word to queue, for typing reasons

    def getY(self):
        return self.y_point

    def draw(self):
        #creates a new object
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS' ,30)
        #creates a new surface with text drawn on it
        textsurface = myfont.render(self.word, False, (0,0,0))

        self.screen.blit(textsurface,(self.x_point,self.y_point))
```

Comment: Comparing key presses to  characters has many issues. For example you often need multiple key presses to compose one character. The problems start with shift keys on Latin keyboards, the get worse for accents. Eventually the correspondence between key and characters becomes immense when IME (input method editors) are used for scripts like Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: I was thinking I could do if K_a == 'a' or something similar but you can't really compare the variable name itself as far as I know (since k_a, k_b etc is a variable in pygame) . Right now,  I'm thinking of just letting the user type in console and compare it to the word then as a work around.

Comment: A map between keys and characters might help, but without showing what  code you have written so far, it is almost impossible to help.
I suggest that you read up on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. The help sections give good advice.

Comment: I edited in my code. But I think a map would be good. Thanks!

Comment: event [KEYDOWN](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) has `event.unicode`, `event.key`, `event.mod` . ie. `event.unicode == "a"` or even `event.unicode.lower() == "a"` to get "a" and "A".

Answer (score 1):

Event [KEYDOWN](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) has `event.unicode`, `event.key`, `event.mod`

You can compare

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.unicode == "a":
```

or even

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.unicode.lower() == "a":
```

to check `"a"` and `"A"`

To check char in word

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  
    if event.unicode.lower() in your_word.lower():
```

---

Example code use `event.unicode` to render text with pressed keys.

BTW: It is not some `Entry` widget so it doesn't delete char when you press `backspace`.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE =  (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED =   (255,   0,   0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 300
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200

FPS = 5  # `FPS = 25` is enough for human eye to see animation.
         # If your program don't use animation
         # then `FPS = 5` or even `FPS = 1` can be enough

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

text = ""

text_image = font.render(text, True, GREEN)
text_rect = text_image.get_rect()     # get current size
text_rect.center = screen_rect.center # center on screen

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False

while not done:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            text += event.unicode

            text_image = font.render(text, True, GREEN)
            text_rect = text_image.get_rect()     # get current size
            text_rect.center = screen_rect.center # center on screen

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    screen.blit(text_image, text_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -
pygame.quit() # <-- quit(), not init()
```

[image]